# Using Google Drive API Libraries and Play with Java freezes/locks up application when attempting to save credentials

Tags: java, playframework, google-drive-api, playframework-2.0

I am using the Google Drive API libraries/code in my Play Framework application using Java.  I have the credentials set correctly in my GCP project in the API section.  I am still learning how these Google libraries and the code I am using is from some posts I found, so I do not understand why it freezes and not sure how to fix it.

I have code that works fine when running the application locally (`http://localhost:9000`).  However, when I run on the server, it freezes/locks up when it attempts to save the credentials - it never returns an error or message.  I have waited up to 15 minutes with no response.  Here is the line of code:

```
credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

Here is the class that I am using:

```
package google;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.Details;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import controllers.GlobalUtilities.StringControl;
import play.Configuration;
import play.Logger;

public class GoogleDrive {

    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "PTP";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
            ".credentials/ptpgoogledrive");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials at
     * ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
     */
    // private static final List<String> SCOPES =
    // Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * 
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = null;
        String credentialsFileName = "";
        try {
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Starting...");

            // Set up the credentials...
            String clientID = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.credentials.clientID");
            String clientSecret = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.credentials.clientSecret");
            String authURI = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.credentials.authURI");
            String tokenURI = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.credentials.tokenURI");
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: clientID = " + clientID);
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: clientSecret = " + clientSecret);
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: authURI = " + authURI);
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: tokenURI = " + tokenURI);

            GoogleClientSecrets.Details details = new Details();
            details.setClientId(clientID);
            details.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
            details.setAuthUri(authURI);
            details.setTokenUri(tokenURI);
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = new GoogleClientSecrets().setInstalled(details);

            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Found client secrets...");
            if (clientSecrets == null) {
                Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: GoogleClientSecrets is null...");
            }

            // Build flow and trigger user authorization request...
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Setting GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow...");
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
                    clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").build();
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow has been set...");
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Setting credenital...");
            credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            System.out.println("Could not find file " + credentialsFileName);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Ending...");
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
     * 
     * @return an authorized Drive client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: getDriveService: Starting...");
        Credential credential = null;
        Drive googleDrive = null;
        try {
            credential = authorize();
            googleDrive = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return googleDrive;
    }

    public static String getPath() {
        String s = GoogleDrive.class.getName();
        int i = s.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (i > -1)
            s = s.substring(i + 1);
        s = s + ".class";
        System.out.println("Class Name: " + s);
        Object testPath = GoogleDrive.class.getResource(s);
        System.out.println("Current Path: " + testPath);
        return "";
    }

    public static String uploadFile(java.io.File file) throws IOException {
        String fileID = "";
        try {
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Starting File Upload...");
            // Build a new authorized API client service.
            Drive service = getDriveService();
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Completed Drive Service...");
            String fullFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Full File Path: " + fullFilePath);
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            String fileName = StringControl.rightBack(fullFilePath, "\\");
            String fileContentType = getContentType(fileName);
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: File Content Type: " + fileContentType);
            fileMetadata.setName(fileName);
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: File Name = " + fileName);
            // Set the folder...
            String folderID = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.folderid");
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Folder ID = " + folderID);
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderID));

            java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(fullFilePath);
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(fileContentType, filePath);
            File fileToUpload = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).setFields("id, parents").execute();
            fileID = fileToUpload.getId();
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: File ID: " + fileID);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Ending File Upload...");
        return fileID;
    }

    public static String getContentType(String filePath) throws Exception {
        String type = "";
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
            type = Files.probeContentType(path);
            System.out.println(type);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return type;
    }

}
```

I have a bunch of logging to determine where the code freezes and here is the output:

```
GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Starting File Upload...
GoogleDrive: getDriveService: Starting...
GoogleDrive: authorize: Starting...
GoogleDrive: authorize: clientID = (my client ID)
GoogleDrive: authorize: clientSecret = (my client secret)
GoogleDrive: authorize: authURI = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
GoogleDrive: authorize: tokenURI = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
GoogleDrive: authorize: Found client secrets...
GoogleDrive: authorize: Setting GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow...
GoogleDrive: authorize: GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow has been set...
GoogleDrive: authorize: Setting credenital...
```

As you can see, it never gets to the next logging output:

```
Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
```

I appreciate if you could show me what I am missing with a sample or fixing my code above.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer to this was to use a Service Account instead of OAuth2.

I created a Service Account in my Google Cloud Platform project:

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/

I used the default account for my Compute Engine instance and created the key needed and downloaded the file to my machine and referenced in my code above.

The files are uploaded without a problem.

Here is my final code:

```
package google;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

import controllers.GlobalUtilities.StringControl;
import play.Configuration;
import play.Logger;

public class GoogleDrive {

    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "PTP";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
            ".credentials/ptpgoogledrive");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials at
     * ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * 
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static GoogleCredential authorize() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        String credentialsFileName = "";
        try {
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Starting...");

            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Getting credentialsFileName path...");
            credentialsFileName = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.credentials.file");
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: credentialsFileName = " + credentialsFileName);

            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Setting InputStream...");
            InputStream in = GoogleDrive.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(credentialsFileName);
            if (in == null) {
                Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: InputStream is null");
            }
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: InputStream set...");

            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Setting credential...");
            credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(in, HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
                    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            System.out.println("Could not find file " + credentialsFileName);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: authorize: Ending...");
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
     * 
     * @return an authorized Drive client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: getDriveService: Starting...");
        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        Drive googleDrive = null;
        try {
            credential = authorize();
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: getDriveService: Credentials set...");
            googleDrive = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return googleDrive;
    }

    public static String getPath() {
        String s = GoogleDrive.class.getName();
        int i = s.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (i > -1)
            s = s.substring(i + 1);
        s = s + ".class";
        System.out.println("Class Name: " + s);
        Object testPath = GoogleDrive.class.getResource(s);
        System.out.println("Current Path: " + testPath);
        return "";
    }

    public static String uploadFile(java.io.File file, String folderIDToFind) throws IOException {
        String fileID = "";
        String fileName = "";
        try {
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Starting File Upload...");
            // Build a new authorized API client service.
            Drive service = getDriveService();
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Completed Drive Service...");

            // Set the folder...
            String folderID = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.folderid");
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Folder ID = " + folderID);

            String folderIDToUse = getSubfolderID(service, folderID, folderIDToFind);

            String fullFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Full File Path: " + fullFilePath);
            File fileMetadata = new File();

            // Let's see what slashes exist to get the correct file name...
            if (fullFilePath.contains("/")) {
                fileName = StringControl.rightBack(fullFilePath, "/");
            } else {
                fileName = StringControl.rightBack(fullFilePath, "\\");
            }
            String fileContentType = getContentType(fileName);
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: File Content Type: " + fileContentType);
            fileMetadata.setName(fileName);
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: File Name = " + fileName);

            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Setting the folder...");
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderIDToUse));
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Folder set...");

            // Team Drive settings...
            fileMetadata.set("supportsTeamDrives", true);

            java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(fullFilePath);

            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(fileContentType, filePath);

            File fileToUpload = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).setSupportsTeamDrives(true)
                    .setFields("id, parents").execute();

            fileID = fileToUpload.getId();
            Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: File ID: " + fileID);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Ending File Upload...");
        return fileID;
    }

    public static String getContentType(String filePath) throws Exception {
        String type = "";
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
            type = Files.probeContentType(path);
            System.out.println(type);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return type;
    }

    public static String getSubfolderID(Drive service, String parentFolderID, String folderKeyToGet) {
        // We need to see if the folder exists based on the ID...
        String folderID = "";
        Boolean foundFolder = false;
        FileList result = null;
        File newFolder = null;

        // Set the drive query...
        String driveQuery = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '" + parentFolderID
                + "' in parents and name contains '" + folderKeyToGet + "' and trashed=false";

        try {
            result = service.files().list().setQ(driveQuery).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (File folder : result.getFiles()) {
            System.out.printf("Found folder: %s (%s)\n", folder.getName(), folder.getId());
            foundFolder = true;
            folderID = folder.getId();
        }
        if (foundFolder != true) {
            // Need to create the folder...
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            fileMetadata.setName(folderKeyToGet);
            fileMetadata.setTeamDriveId(parentFolderID);
            fileMetadata.set("supportsTeamDrives", true);
            fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(parentFolderID));

            try {
                newFolder = service.files().create(fileMetadata).setSupportsTeamDrives(true).setFields("id, parents")
                        .execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Send back the folder ID...
            folderID = newFolder.getId();
            System.out.println("Folder ID: " + newFolder.getId());
        }

        return folderID;
    }


}
```

I hope this helps the next guy.